# How to get all assembly references using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-assembly, mono.cecil

I'm using [**Mono.Cecil**](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) to inspect a portable class library I've built. I'm wondering how to get all of the referenced assemblies after I read the DLL in, much like how ILSpy does it. Can anyone help? Here is the code I have so far:

```
var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(assemblyPath);

// No `References` or `GetReferences()` property on the
// resulting object, so I'm confused about what to do here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I'm blind. You can do this via the `AssemblyReferences` property:

```
var references = module.AssemblyReferences;
```

Comment: ILSpy is open source :) so you can also search for Mono.Cecil usage in its code base. PCL assemblies have strange references so resolving them at runtime is quite different.